# Replace : and any char after that using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following strings

```
var s1 = "Group:0.Devices.Cabins:0.Position.GroupStop:0.GroupStop";
var s2 = "Group.Devices.State:15X.GenericState";
var s3 = "Group.Devices.State.HealthState";
var s4 = "Group:1.Devices:7A.Cabins:0.Doors:0.State:0";
```

I need to remove `:` and `any char` after it .Expected result:

```
Group.Devices.Cabins.Position.GroupStop.GroupStop
Group.Devices.State.GenericState
Group.Devices.State.HealthState
Group.Devices.Cabins.Doors.State
```

I used something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s1, @"\:.*?\.", "."), @"\:.*?$", ""));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s2, @"\:.*?\.", "."), @"\:.*?$", ""));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s3, @"\:.*?\.", "."), @"\:.*?$", ""));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s4, @"\:.*?\.", "."), @"\:.*?$", ""));
```

It works, but are there any more efficient ways how to do that? I want to use it with compiled regex.

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"....", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Then `_regex.Replace(s1, string.Empty);`

Could you please help me to merge 2 regex into one?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You may also try `Regex.Replace(s4, ":.+?(\\.|$)?", "$1")`.

Comment: @SGKoishi thanks but why not `:[^.]*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative character classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions?view=netframework-4.8#NegativeGroup) to create a single regular expression matching the portion of the text you want to remove. I match colon followed by zero or more non-full stop characters:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var s1 = "Group:0.Devices.Cabins:0.Position.GroupStop:0.GroupStop";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s1, @":[^.]*", "")); // Group.Devices.Cabins.Position.GroupStop.GroupStop
```

*[sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwDoAVAUwA8FqAlegc1QBsJkBRRgAdk9AM5ioAexhiA3MWIA3PuTF5yAXnIAiAOLIpqISFLUAIvSVQAxuOoBhCMFhjT1AApTJCaTGoGRkIAyghSJmaBxqHhOgokeACcABTsHExs9EK8dsnqcJRYOiAA2gB61AC6AFQ6BTo6AJSNcuQA9G3kUUIWVrb2Ti6ynt5QvjIBhtFhPd0xQsRAA===)*